# Create Circular Image Xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

In windows phone 8 I want to put an Image in a circle. Is there a container like grid which have a circular form? I know that there is ellipse bit it is not a container

Comment: might setting a 50% corner radius on a square achieve what you want?

Comment: I didn't undertand very well. Are you trying to say that I have to create square, set the radius to 50% and then add the Image? (I can't do that because the square is not a container)

Comment: I haven't used Windows phone 8, but in some other markups you can set the border radius of each corner of a square to make a circle. In css you'd do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/M97Fz/1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is how I do it.

```
<Ellipse Width="100"
         Height="100">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush>
            <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                <BitmapImage UriSource="/YourImage.png" />
            </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
        </ImageBrush>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

As a best practice, consider setting `DecodePixelWidth` and `DecodePixelHeight` to the same size as your ellipse.

Comment: When doing this with an image loaded in memory (not from a URI), I ended up binding directly to the `ImageSource` property directly on the `ImageBrush` element.

Answer (score 8):

Another option to mleroy's answer (since if I remember right WP is based on silverlight and I often run into a lack of brush availability to do stuff like that.) You could do this using the `Clip` property.

For example;

```
<Image 
  Source="blah\yourpicture.jpg" 
  Width="100" Height="100">
  <Image.Clip>
    <EllipseGeometry
      RadiusX="100"
      RadiusY="100"
      Center="100,100"/>
  </Image.Clip>
</Image>
```

Hope this helps, cheers

Edit Addition: You could also bind your radius X/Y to the width/height of the image for more flexibility on dynamic sized images.

Comment: Heads up, EllipseGeometry isn't available in Windows 10 Universal Apps.

Comment: Yep, but the question wasn't for that and is over a year old. Good to pass on though.