# How to clip an image in a round way, without knowing its dimensions in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I have an image element in my XAML, and I don't want to specify its dimensions because I'd like it to scale according to the resolution of the display size.

I need to clip the image in a circle, how can I do it without explicitly stating its dimensions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Circular Image Xaml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23138878/create-circular-image-xaml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret your question that you want to make a circular image which fills the parent container. Using an ellipse with `Stretch="Uniform"` to create a circle and then set the `Fill` to the image which is placed inside a `Grid` for example it will fill it's parent, example:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <Ellipse Stretch="Uniform">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/avatarpic-l.png" />
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>
</Grid>
```

This will give the following result:

[image]

There is also an alternative method which produces the same result using `OpacityMask` (by varying the `Offset` parameters you can also get some nice fade effects):

```
<Image Source="/Assets/avatarpic-l.png">
    <Image.OpacityMask>
        <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5" Center="0.5,0.5" RadiusX="0.5" RadiusY="0.5">
            <GradientStop Color="#ffffffff" Offset="1.0" />
            <GradientStop Color="#00ffffff" Offset="1.0" /> 
        </RadialGradientBrush>
    </Image.OpacityMask>
</Image>
```

With this second approach if you set `<Image Source="/Assets/avatarpic-l.png" Stretch="None" >...</Image>` you can get the image to maintain its original dimensions too.