# ImageBrush issue Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I need to create a round image in a windows phone universal app.

for creating this kind of image i have used this code :

```
<Border CornerRadius="30" Height="60" Width="60">
    <Border.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/round_image.png" />
    </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

but this code has a huge memory impact, about 4Mb for each image.
using this code instead fix the issue, but the image is not round.

```
<Border CornerRadius="30" Height="60" Width="60">
        <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/round_image.png" Stretch="Fill" />
</Border>
```

I need to display 20 images, the difference with this 2 approaches is about 80mb.

there is a solution to this memory issue?

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23138878/create-circular-image-xaml/23139155#23139155) still applies to 8.1

Comment: Yes it's a solution but still doesn't solve my memory issue

Comment: Border is a templated control, using just a shape should have some sort of benefit to your performance issue. I'd also have to ask, how big are the actual image assets and how they're being loaded.

Comment: The images are a variable size, and the image are loaded from the assets, I have tried your solution, but it seams tath the issue is the imagebrush

Comment: Did you try Clip instead?

Comment: @Chris In WinRT apps, `Clip` only supports the `RectangleGeometry`. `EllipseGeometry` is not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<Border CornerRadius="30" Height="60" Width="60">
    <Border.Background>
            <ImageBrush>
                <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                    <BitmapImage
                        UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/round_image.png" 
                        DecodePixelWidth="60"
                        DecodePixelHeight="60"
                        DecodePixelType="Logical"/>
                </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
            </ImageBrush>
    </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

The problem may be that your images are too large. This will decode the images to the actual display size, which will increase rendering performance if the original images are too large.

Comment: MY image  dimensions 100*100  ...Enclosing  in  a  eclipse (150 * 150) with  image.fill..