# Image within an ellipse XAML

Tags: image, xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am using VS2013, Windows 8.1 and developing a windows store app.

Im creating a simple contacts - listview, that displays the contact details along with contact image within an ellipse. When I click on the listview item, I want to display the contact details on right side of the page. Now the issue I am facing is, I am not able to fit the contact image to the right size on the ellipse on the right side pane. 
I am able to achieve it in my list view since its an smaller ellipse. 
Important: I do not want the image to look stretched/Zoomed in /Zoomed out. It should exactly look like how it appears within the list view. (For list view , I have used Ellipse.Fill along with Imagebrush, but relatively smaller sized ellipse)

What I tried so far:

1. Ellipse.Fill property which paints the image to size, but the image looks stretched.
2. I tried setting "Stretch" property within the image tag within ellipse, but did not work.
3. I tried Image.clip, but I do not have "EllipseGeometry" option, instead only RectangleGeometry.
4. Lastly I created an image that has a transparent center and I place this frame over the contact image like a mask. This works well on some resolutions. But when some other resolution, the contact images which are binded from backend, go beyond the frame, although I set "MaxHeight" or "Height" properties.

I want to do it the right way, since I feel adding an image mask might not be a great way to achieve this. Please help!

I tried this for listview, n works fine, But the same code for right pane looks stretched (I have tried removing stretch attirbute, or tried other options like Stretch ="None" /"Uniform" etc )

I have attached screenshot.

Comment: ` <Ellipse x:Name="smallEllipse"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Height="78" Width="78" Margin="10"  >
 <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ProfileImage}" x:Name="profilePic" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
 </Ellipse.Fill>
 </Ellipse>`

Comment: I tried the above code for listview, & works fine, But the same code for right pane looks stretched (I have tried removing stretch attirbute, or tried other options like Stretch ="None" /"Uniform" etc )

Comment: right now im using this as a mask:
 <Image x:Name="bigEllipse" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="Assets/myConbtactprofImage.png"
 VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="5,10,0,0" MaxHeight="130" ></Image>
  <Image Source="Assets/Frame.gif" Height="145" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Image>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Circular Image Xaml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23138878/create-circular-image-xaml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties "AlignmentX  AlignmentY" within ImageBrush solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since code isn't clearly mentioned, you can do it with both `Ellipse` and `Border`. Here's the code snippet

```
<!--With Ellipse-->
<Ellipse Height="200"
         Width="200">
         <Ellipse.Fill>
             <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform"
                         ImageSource="Assets/profile.png" />
         </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>


<!--With Border-->
<Border Height="200"
        Width="200"
        CornerRadius="150">
        <Border.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform"
                        ImageSource="Assets/profile.png" />
        </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

Here's the result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your image has portrait orientation, then you can use Stretch, AlignmentX, AlignmentY properties of ImageBrush like this to achieve best preview result

```
<Border CornerRadius="20" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGoldenrod">
        <Ellipse Width="40" Height="40">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding PractitionerPhoto}"  Stretch="UniformToFill" AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Top" />
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
    </Border>
```